# You의 여러가지 주격대명사 무엇인가요?

Tags: word-usage

은행 서신을 읽으면서 모른 단어가 봤어요. 그 서신이 여러번 그 단어를 되뇌지고 있으니까 가 간어의 뜻은 아마 you 되지 생각했어요. 하지만, '구'저름 사작하는 그런 주격 대명사가 있으면 저는 모르겠습나다. 선생님은 저를 좀 얼려주실 수 있어요,  부턱드립나다.

I asked Quora and Reddit if there was a 2nd person subject pronoun in Korean that begins with the characters 구 and so far no one has been able to answer my question. So, I am turning to you for an answer.

Comment: Please post the sentence where you saw this  '구' if available.

Comment: There is no 2nd person subject pronoun starting with '구'. Is it '귀하' ?

Comment: Likely “귀하 (貴下).” It’s a polite way of saying “you” in written business letters.

Answer (score 2):

This just a guess, but one (formerly) common word used by the bank starting with 구 would be 구좌 which means an account.  It has been replaced by 계좌 which has the same meaning, and neither of these words can mean "you" in any context.

Banks and other businesses most commonly (or almost exclusively) call their customers **고객님** (**고객** = customer, **님** = honorific suffix), both verbally and in written communication. I am wondering whether you are mixing up 고 with 구, because there really isn't any other word they might use for "you", let alone one starting with 구.